# looping through sql insert statement to generate multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

So I know this is deprecated and unsafe, but it's one of the last things i am trying to work through before switching over to SQLi. I don't think this being in SQL should complicate it too much. Anyways, I am trying to loop through to generate a row for each userid input into the _POST 'userids' field. It is part of a relatively simple multi-recipient message system

```
    if (empty($_POST['userids'])) {
        echo "no user ids input";
        }  
    $seq = 1;
    $uids = explode(',', $_POST['userids']);
    $uids[] = $sess_username;  
    $uids = array_unique($uids);

        print_r(array_values($uids));

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($uids as $uid) {
                $rows[] = array('uid'=>(int)$uid);
    }

        print_r(array_values($rows));

        if (!$uids) {
            die('No user ids selected: ' . mysql_error());


    if (empty($messageid)) {
        $messageid = mysql_insert_id();
        }
   $insertSql = "INSERT INTO message_recips (messageid, sequence, userid, status) VALUES";

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        $insertSql .= "(" . $params[] = $messageid . "," . $params[] = $seq . "," . $params[] = $row['uid'] . ",'" . $params[] = $row['uid'] == $sess_user_id ? 'A' : 'N' . "'),";
    }

    $insertSql = substr($insertSql, 0, -1);

    var_dump($insertSql);
    var_dump($params);

    $result1 = mysql_query($insertSql);

    echo "$insertSql";


    var_dump($insertSql);
    var_dump($params);
    if (!stmt) {
        "sql error after stmt";
    }

    die(header('Location: view.php?id=' . $mid));
} else {

    echo "no recips found";
    die('no recips found');
}
```

my array is populating with:

```
array (size=8)
0 => int 35
1 => int 1
2 => int 273
3 => string 'N' (length=1)
5 => int 1
6 => int 0
7 => string 'N' (length=1)
```

and my sql result is:

```
string 'INSERT INTO message_recips VALUES('35', '1', 'Array', 'Array')' (length=62)
```

The array looks good to me, but its only generating one row in my SQL table and inserting the first four values into that row.

A sincere thanks for any help.-a

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: nope. just the array.  First 4 of the array go in alright, so I guess I wouldn't expect an error.

Comment: I'm not an sql expert, but I have never seen the columns left out when inserting into a table, can you do that?

Comment: changed that, but to no avail, I found a doc here that might help: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Insert-Multiple-Rows-Into-MySQL-The-Right-Way-With-PHP.html

Comment: I am just examining your code in detail I think I know how to fix it, but I need to fix a syntax error you have in your code and a couple other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this gets you closer to your needs. I have commented where changes are.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(empty($_POST['userids'])) {
        echo "no user ids input";
    }
else {
        $seq    =   1;
        $uids   =   explode(',', $_POST['userids']);
        $uids[] =   $sess_username;  
        $uids   =   array_unique($uids);

        foreach($uids as $uid) {
                $rows[] = array('uid'=> (int)$uid);
            }

        // You have a syntax error here         
        if (!$uids)
            die('No user ids selected: ' . mysql_error());

        if(empty($messageid))
            $messageid = mysql_insert_id();

        // Set a multi-dimensional array
        $i  =   0;
        foreach($rows as $row) {
                $params[$i][]   =   "'$messageid'";
                $params[$i][]   =   "'$seq'";
                $params[$i][]   =   "'".$row['uid']."'";
                $params[$i][]   =   ($row['uid'] == $sess_user_id)? "'A'" : "'N'";
                $i++;
            }

        // Set front of sql statement, I am just placeholding column names, you need to change them
        $insertSql   = "INSERT INTO message_recips (`message_id`,`seq`,`uid`,`session`) VALUES";

        // Implode the values generated above
        foreach($params as $arrays) {
                $values[]   =   "(".implode(",",$arrays).")";
            }

        // Implode the multiple rows
        $sqls   =   implode(",",$values);
        // Combine front with end
        $sql    =   $insertSql.$sqls;

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: gosh, thanks for all the help. First plug in didn't work but I'll tinker with it and get back to you. I know I should be using the implode, so that is great that you added it in there. Thanks again.

Comment: If you post your input array and what you think your sql  should look like it would be easy to figure out

Comment: I just added what made it work... for whatever reason the implode wasn't working but I just added a comma to the end of the repeating statement and trimmed it with a substr(). I know yours is the correct was though, as that is exactly how it is in the docs. Thanks again for working through this with me.